# Network settings to execute webapplication performance tests from Windows Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, tcp, connection, jmeter

Web applications needs to be tested from a `Windows Server 2012 R2` machine. Performance tests are executed with `JMeter 5.3` on 300-400 threads. During test execution, following errors are coming in JMeter, 1-2 per seconds after 20 seconds of test run:

> Response code:Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException
> Response message:Non HTTP response message: Connection reset

I searched about this error and found, that it is probably caused by the setting of maximum number of TCP connections, that can be opened simultaneously.
Output of `Get-Item 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters'` :

> ```
>                            UseDomainNameDevolution      : 1
>                            EnableICMPRedirect           : 1
>                            DeadGWDetectDefault          : 1
>                            DontAddDefaultGatewayDefault : 0
>                            KeepAliveTime                : 900000
>                            KeepAliveInterval            : 10000
>                            NV Domain                    : m53.local
>                            ShutDownTimeAtLastDomainJoin : {11, 189, 171, 150...}
>                            (default)                    :
>                            TcpTimedWaitDelay            : 60
>                            MaxUserPort                  : 65534
>                            TcpNumConnections            : 16777214
>                            TcpMaxDataRetransmissions    : 10
> ```

It seems size of TCP pool is enough, system has 16 GB RAM memory. How could I optimize system for performance testing?

Answer (score 1):

1. This "Connection Reset" might be caused by the system under test so I would start from checking its logs.
2. If you're absolutely sure that it's JMeter to blame you can consider following recommendations from [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki page
3. You might want to reduce TcpTimedWaitDelay to `30` so ephemeral ports would recycle faster
4. You might want to add [`javax.net.debug=all` line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512522/log-all-network-interactions-of-java-application) to *system.properties* file to see what's going on under the hood
5. You might want to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for HTTP protocol by adding the next lines to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="debug" />
   ```
6. And finally some people state that changing [HTTP Request implementation to Java](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) helped, as the last resort you can switch it using HTTP Request Defaults:

   [image]